# Why does API Gateway (Test) not wait for async lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am writing an async lambda on AWS using Node.js (14.x). This lambda is being called by an API Gateway (REST API, POST method, CORS enabled).

To allow the API Gateway to call an async lambda, I added the following HTTP Header to its Integration Request: Name = `X-Amz-Invocation-Type` and Mapped from (value) = `'Event'` [as specified here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html).

When I run Test, I get the following output:

```
Execution log for request BLAH
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Starting execution for request: BLAH
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: BLAH
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Method request path: {}
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Method request query string: {}
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Method request headers: {}
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Method request body before transformations: {
  "id": "BLAH",
  "recaptcha": "BLAH"
}
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Request validation succeeded for content type application/json
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.BLAH.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:BLAH:function:BLAH/invocations
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request headers: {X-Amz-Date=BLAH, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=BLAH, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_BLAH, Host=lambda.BLAH.amazonaws.com, X-Amz-Content-Sha256=BLAH, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=BLAH, x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=BLAH, Authorization=*****BLAH*****, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:BLAH/test-invoke-stage/POST/BLAH, X-Amz-Invocation-Type=Event, X-Amz-Security-Token=BLAH [TRUNCATED]
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {
  "id": "BLAH",
  "recaptcha": "BLAH"
}
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Sending request to https://lambda.BLAH.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:BLAH:function:BLAH/invocations
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Received response. Status: 202, Integration latency: 34 ms
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Fri, 26 Mar 2021 07:30:34 GMT, Content-Length=0, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=BLAH, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=BLAH;sampled=0}
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response body before transformations: 
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Method response body after transformations: 
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=BLAH;Sampled=0, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*, Content-Type=application/json}
Fri Mar 26 07:30:34 UTC 2021 : Successfully completed execution
```

Note that the response gives `Status: 202` and that there is no response body. **No matter what code I put in my lambda, this seems to be the case.** Here are a couple basic examples that I've tried:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js and set the region.
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'BLAH'});

// Main function, responds to AWS API Gateway.
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    var response = {
        httpStatus : 200,
        message : "Success"
    };
    return JSON.stringify(response);
};
```

and

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js and set the region.
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'BLAH'});

// Main function, responds to AWS API Gateway.
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var response = {
            httpStatus : 200,
            message : "Success"
        };
        resolve(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
    return promise;
};
```

I made sure to deploy the API and Lambda. **How can I get a non-202 status (i.e. get the API Gateway to wait on the async lambda)?**

Comment: Well, which one do you want? Do you want a synchronous result body or not - an async invocation does not produce a result / body, a synchronous does. You cannot have an async lambda and wait for its response, at that point you no longer have an async lambda. From the docs: *"In this case, the backend Lambda function is invoked asynchronously, and the front-end REST API method doesn't return the result."*

Comment: @luk2302 I had the following (incorrect) mental model: the frontend (website) can go back to its business (rather than be unresponsive to the user), but when the async process finally finishes, the frontend can handle that response. But instead it seems no response is possible (other than 200) once it gets to the asynchronous lambda. So my question is: if something in the lambda fails (e.g. recaptcha validation or adding data to SQS), is there any way to notify the website / user of this? Should my website POST data to a synchronous lambda instead (via API Gateway)??

Comment: For APIs most of the time you want to have synchronous invocations. Maybe the lambda only inserts a row in the dynamodb, returns its id and triggers another lambda that does the heavy lifting of the work but that is up to you decide. In particular you need to ask yourself if the API should model the operation as its own entity, does creating a customer entity take so long and so much work and should be cancelable in the meantime then it is time to actually have a CustomerCreationRequest resource in your API. But still you will probably have synchronous lambdas that dispatches e.g. sqs messages

Comment: @luk2302 I had started with a synchronous lambda, but switched based on some AWS docs (e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html lists "Sample Lambda applications in Node.js", and the API Gateway one is asynchronous: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/nodejs-apig/function/index.js). I really only do two things in the lambda: check validity of recaptcha and then add to SQS (for others to process). I'll shift back to synchronous - thanks.

Comment: Nope, that is not an async lambda. The code simply uses the language specific `async` keyword but that is ***completely*** unrelated to the infrastructure deploying an asynchronous lambda. Those two have the same term associated, (a)synchronous, but they have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: So is the only aspect related to the "infrastructure deploying an asynchronous lambda" the X-Amz-Invocation-Type = 'Event'  header in the Integration Request??

Comment: Seems like it, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working as intended. The second sentence in [AWS docs on "Asynchronous invocation"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) says:

> When you invoke a function asynchronously, you don't wait for a response from the function code.

If you want a response with a result, asynchronous invocation will not work.

Comment: Adding to this: The API Gateway should use a synchronous (e.g. AWS_PROXY) integration with Lambda, but what happens inside of the Lambda can still be async.

Comment: @Sleavely No, it "should" is certainly the wrong wording to use - because if there was no usecase for the async invocation the feature would not be there. And the lambda generally cannot be really async in itself, you will have to return a response synchronously to the gateway request, yes you can do some async stuff in between but the lambda has to answer synchronously and after it answers it is done processing.